# How to access age restriction parental controls on iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone

is there a way to programmatically access the age restriction set in the parental controls on the iPhone/iPad/iPod? I'd like to disallow features if the age restriction is too low. I've been searching around, but maybe I'm not using the right search terms or something. Any help appreciated. Maybe it just doesn't work this way.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no programmatic access to restrictions as of 3.0. As you probably know, restrictions mostly apply to what applications are permitted to be installed based on their age/content rating in the App Store.

You could, on the other hand, roll your own system whereby a passcode was required for setting which features were available. This would have roughly the same effect, except that the initial app user would be responsible for ensuring that the settings were locked down before the app was used by the sensitive party.

Comment: Does anyone have an app in the app store approved by Apple which does this? Curious about what Apple would say about it, since we have a reader-style app with downloadable content that could (by some overzealous guardians) be considered inappropriate for some ages.

Comment: It's a thin line to walk. Apple still requires you to submit restriction criteria that is applicable to the totality of your content (that is, the "worst" possible content that could be accessed by your app determines its age level). The high age level, in turn, scare away consumers who are looking for age-appropriate content. I think if you were transparent about your own age-restriction features in your App Store submission and your public description, Apple would see the rationale. Consumers are sadly less prone to read fine print. But I think it's worth trying.