# How to access age restriction parental controls - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parental-control

Is there a way to determine if age controls are set so I can restrict functionality in my app.

The reason I want to do this is because my app is 17+ rated and I would like to get this rating down.

1Password has done this with a webview but I don't know if it is possible to detect this in the app.

There is this question [How to access age restriction parental controls on iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503918/how-to-access-age-restriction-parental-controls-on-iphone-sdk)
where the answer is that its not available but since its an old question I was hoping that there would be a new way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that it's not possible. Ios simply does not have the api's for this